# Jasper reporting iterate through a list

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have list of strings that to be passed to the JR report using a *HashMap*. I want to know how to iterate through that list in the *jrxml* file and print the contents of the list.

I use *iReport* as the GUI designer.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you passing the list as a HashMap instead of an actual List? If all you want to do is include a list of values in the report and it's all Strings, you could just build a comma-delimited list and pass it to the jrxml file as 1 String object.

If you have a list of data that needs to be associated with each individual data object, you can create a subreport that takes an ArrayList datasource with your list of things to print, and then include it in the main report.

Comment: How can you add ArrayList as datasource and create report that in detail section iterates over that array?

Comment: In the main report, set the subreport object's data source expression to new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(<dataSourceList>). In the subreport .jrxml file, set the report data source to the class that is in your ArrayList.